# Match pattern and grab argument value using elisp regex returns nil

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

This is my code statement

```
var myStr = require('ssh2')
```

and my elisp regex must return the arg value iff the statement has a require func invocation.

```
 (let ((s "var myStr = require('ssh2')"))
   (if (string-match "'require(\\([^']+\\)'" s)
       (match-string 1 s)))
```

this returns nil, however?
what makes my regex a mess, someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?:

```
"require\(\\(?:'\\(.*\\)'\\)\)"
```

If you haven't already played around with `M-x re-builder RET`, you'll enjoy it.

Here is a link to one of my favorite threads regarding a noncapturing group:

[What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

Comment: it worked... but this pattern,  "require\\(\\(?:'\\(.*\\)'\\)\)" returned nil... the change i have made is put double slashes in the place of single slashes because somewhere i read in elisp, all escapes must be done twice...

Comment: I believe **literal** parentheses are **single**-escaped.  Re-builder will fail if **literal** parentheses are **double**-escaped.  Parentheses that are for *grouping*, are **double**-escaped.   Your example contains an opening *literal* parentheses and a closing *literal* parentheses.